# Finding cell address based on unique value in range

Tags: excel, date, lookup

I have a spreadsheet with calendar, i.e. it contains dates in multiple columns and rows. It is basically split into 4 rows (say 1, 21, 41 and 61), each representing a quarter. Each date has a number of cells beneath it (say 20 but this may vary later) and these contain details for a person in column A (so A2, A22, A42 and A62 has typically the same name of a person) for the date.

On another sheet, I need to do a sort of a cut-out of data around current day's date (I want to display this week and the next week). The data beneath the cell cannot be got be HLOOKUP because the formula will fail with the date moving into the next quarter.

Also I struggled to get the data from the column A (because the row depends on the date). So far I managed to work around it using a helping cell indicating quarter which enabled me to use INDEX-MATCH to find the proper names but only because I had free cells where to put this. This cannot be used, however, for the remaining data because I have neither a priori knowledge of the column or the row where the cell with current date is located. I can estimate the row but when the number of rows between the quarters changes, it will kill the formulas.

EDIT: ok, so INDEX/MATCH ftw...

```
=INDEX('SourceSheet'!$A$1:$CP$100;MATCH($A$19;'SourceSheet'!$A$1:$A$100;0)-(ROW($A$19)-ROW());(B$4-DATE(YEAR(B$4);MONTH(B$4);1)+2))
```

But again, without the helping cell, I would be toast.

**In any case, regardless of my specific problem is there some more elegant method to return cell address if I know its unique value?**

Comment: [Okay.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) What have you tried so far?

Comment: Edited with more information but my question is not around my specific case, which I can work around, but about a general solution for the problem when a cell address needs to be returned if I know only the value of that cell (and this value is unique).

Answer (score 0):

To return an address, you can use:

`=Cell("address",Index([index range],match([unique value],[match range],0)))`

[image]

Comment: No, this works only if the range is one-dimensional. Add values 8,9,5,4 to B2:B5, adjust the formula and it results in an error.